# changing padding for one page only in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to get rid of all padding around the main page elemnts on the front page of my FRC team's website [www.powerhawks.org](http://www.powerhawks.org) because I am re-writing the page. I have a separate page where I am developing the new content that page is [here](http://powerhawks.org/front-page-test/). If I remove all padding from the page element that includes the top menu so I have used inspect element to find that this code affects the element I want to remove padding for.

```
/*  base : layout
/* ------------------------------------ */
#wrapper { min-width: 1024px; height: 100%; }
.container { padding: 0 20px; }
.container-inner { max-width: 1380px; min-width: 1380px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
.main { background-color: #fff!important; position: relative; }
.main-inner { position: relative; min-height: 600px; /* instead of sticky footer */ }
.content { width: 100%; position: relative; }
.pad { padding: 0px 30px 20px; }
```

This is for the entire website though. The only way I know how to make this affect the front page is if I were to edit the div but I need access to the full HTML file for that which I do not know how to find.

Comment: simply use the body's class. If you only want to target specific things on the front page, use `.home <your-selector>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body has unique classes for each page. For example, using `page-id-442` for sponsorship.

Trying putting `.page-id-442` in front of your CSS selector:

`.page-id-442 .container { padding: 0 20px; }`

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I find this class for other pages?

Comment: You can find it in your page's source code. For "home", it's on line 141: <body class="home page page-id-1222 page-template-default _masterslider _ms_version_2.2.1 col-2cl full-width chrome">